# Is there a better way to retrieve values from a Map

Tags: java, collections, lambda, guava

I've the following code

```
final Map<String, Location> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("1", new Location("a", null));
map.put("2", new Location("b", null));
map.put("3", new Location("c", null));

final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (final Location s : map.values()) {
    list.add(s.getId());
}
```

The result is a,b,c (as expected) when I print the list.

```
for (final String string : list) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Is there a better way of getting the Id's without using the for loop in **Java6**.

As per Java8, referencing the code form @rohit-jain answer

```
final List<String> list = map.values().stream().map(loc -> loc.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there anything this consise in java6?

Comment: Could you be more specific by what you mean when you say efficient? At some level you need to iterate over the entries in the map if you want to print them. There is now way around that.

Comment: Also, note that the result could very well be c, a, b or b, a, c or any other combination.

Comment: For clarification, efficiency means can I get rid of the 1st for loop. I know that I would need the 2nd one to print and that's inevitable.

Comment: No. There is no better way of doing it.

Comment: `for (final Location s : map.values()) {
    System.out.println(s.getId());
}`. No need to create a temporary list if all you want to do is print the values.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about efficiency (because it wouldn't affect much), but if you want to do that using lambdas, it can be like this:

```
final Map<String, Location> locationMap = new HashMap<>();
locationMap.put("1", new Location("a", null));
locationMap.put("2", new Location("b", null));
locationMap.put("3", new Location("c", null));

final List<String> list = locationMap.values().stream()
                             .map(loc -> loc.getId())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);  // can be `[a, b, c]` or `[b, c, a]`, etc
```

But, just because you don't see `for` loop here doesn't mean that it isn't iterating over the values of the map. It does, but just hides the iteration logic.

Or, if you just want to print the value (one time usage), you can even avoid creating a list there:

```
locationMap.values().stream().map(loc -> loc.getId())
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: You won me by seconds! ;) Maybe terminal operation could be a `forEach(System.out::println)`. This way, only 1 `for` would take place, as the OP is requesting.

Comment: Printing was secondary, I know that even using lambdas at least 1 pass over the values will happen, My question is can I write this code more concisely in java6 the way we do in java8. I apologise if the question is misleading

Comment: @SDS In Java 6, no. That's the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 3):

> EDIT: The question was modified, and now does no longer seem to refer to efficiency. Now, this answer does not really fit any more, but for now, I'll leave it here, maybe someone finds it helpful

First a general hint: You said

> The result is a,b,c (as expected) when I print the list.

However, you should **not** expect that. The `HashMap` is not sorted in any way. The order of the elments could be different. And also important: If you added *more* elements to the map, then the order of the elements that have previously be contained in the map may *change*!

If you want the order of the elements during the iteration to be the same as the insertion order, you should use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`. It preserves the iteration order, and there, your expectation about the output would be met.

Interestingly, this leads to the question about the performance:

Iterating over a `LinkedHashMap` in fact can be (noticably) faster than iterating over a `Map`. Here's a small microbenchmark, which, as always, should be taken with a grain of salt:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class MapIteration
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int size=100000; size<=1000000; size += 100000)
        {
            Map<String, Integer> mapA = 
                new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            fillMap(mapA, size);

            Map<String, Integer> mapB = 
                new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
            fillMap(mapB, size);

            int runs = 100;
            long beforeA = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i=0; i<runs; i++)
            {
                sum += computeValueSum(mapA);
            }
            long afterA = System.nanoTime();
            double durationA = (afterA - beforeA) / 1e6;

            long beforeB = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i=0; i<runs; i++)
            {
                sum += computeValueSum(mapB);
            }
            long afterB = System.nanoTime();
            double durationB = (afterB - beforeB) / 1e6;

            System.out.printf(
                "Normal size %10d duration %10.3f\n", size, durationA);
            System.out.printf(
                "Linked size %10d duration %10.3f\n", size, durationB);

        }
        System.out.println(sum);

    }

    private static void fillMap(Map<String, Integer> map, int n)
    {
        Random random = new Random(0);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            map.put(String.valueOf(i), random.nextInt(n));
        }
    }

    private static long computeValueSum(Map<?, Integer> map)
    {
        long sum = 0;
        for (Integer i : map.values())
        {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

For me, it prints...

```
...
Normal size    1000000 duration   2611,288
Linked size    1000000 duration   1796,030
```

Again, this should not be taken for granted, unless it is verified with a proper Micobenchmarking framework, but frankly: The `LinkedHashMap` is 30% faster, give or take a few, and I doubt that a Micobenchmarking framework will tell me the opposite here.

---

<sub>In general, I basically *always* use `LinkedHashMap` instead of a plain `HashMap`. But not because of the performance, but mainly because of the consistent iteration order. Regarding the performance: The insertions and deletions in a `LinkedHashMap` may be a tad more expensive than for a `HashMap`, but these performance differences are negligible in most cases.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections), you can write the following:

```
MutableMap<String, Location> map = Maps.mutable.empty();
map.put("1", new Location("a", null));
map.put("2", new Location("b", null));
map.put("3", new Location("c", null));

List<String> list = map.collect(Location::getId).toSortedList();
Bag<String> bag = map.collect(Location::getId);

Assert.assertEquals(Lists.mutable.with("a", "b", "c"), list);
Assert.assertEquals(Bags.mutable.with("a", "b", "c"), bag);
```

The following code will also work with Java 5 - 7:

```
Function<Location, String> function = new Function<Location, String>()
{
    public String valueOf(Location location)
    {
        return location.getId();
    }
};
List<String> list = map.collect(function).toSortedList();
Bag<String> bag = map.collect(function);

Assert.assertEquals(Lists.mutable.with("a", "b", "c"), list);
Assert.assertEquals(Bags.mutable.with("a", "b", "c"), bag);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 2):

If you like to use a Java 6 compatible version, then you could use Guava and its [`Function`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) interface:

```
public class ExtractLocationId implements Function<Location, String> {
     @Override
     public String apply(final Location location) {
          return location.getId();
     }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
final List<String> list =
    FluentIterable.from(map.values()).transform(new ExtractLocationId()).toList();
```

It needs more code than the Java 8 Lambda version (due to the own `Function` implementation) but it supports older Java versions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run away from iteration over map at some point.
For maps most efficient way is to iterate over "entrySet()".

Comment: Why would iterating over entrySet be more efficient than iterating over the values, if the OP doesn't care about the keys?

Comment: due to overall performance, iterating over entries of the map is faster, then over either keys or values.

Comment: @Dae Can you prove that? I mean, when talking about efficiency, I don't believe on words..

Comment: @Dae you should read the source code. You'll realize that the iterator over the values is the same as the iterator on the entries, except it returns the value instead of the entry.

Comment: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/01/performance-comparison-of-different-ways-to-iterate-over-hashmap/

Comment: @Dae Well, this link is not a good source for your performance statement, because their `keySet`-Version does something what OP doesn't need: it calls `Map#get(key)`. But you're right, the entry set *is* better if you need both key and value.